# Fresh seasonal produce - with or without a comma?

Tags: commas

Is a comma required or preferred between **fresh** and **seasonal** in the following phrase?

> Fresh seasonal produce

I suspect the answer hinges on whether **fresh** and **seasonal** can be swapped around. If they cannot, then no commas should be added.

Comment: Neither. When in doubt, the best rule of thumb is *not* to include commas, which are generally in decline anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Commas are a matter of convention.

You might include a comma if you were developing a specification for a school lunch program, say:

> ... fresh, locally grown, non-GMO produce shall be served at every meal.

A comma there would be understood to mean that each term in the list is to be regarded as a discrete item in the spec.

But if you're just describing the produce you can use a comma or not at your discretion:

> Fresh seasonal produce is all we serve here at Fast Food Is Us™.

Comment: Is it natural to say "seasonal fresh produce"?

Comment: I think you can, https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seasonal+fresh+produce%2C+fresh+seasonal+produce+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cseasonal%20fresh%20produce%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfresh%20seasonal%20produce%3B%2Cc0

Comment: **fresh** is a qualitative opinion and would normally appear before **seasonal** which is an objective attribute.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo In that case, when an adjective or other modifier forms a "closer" unit with the noun, there should be no comma between the unit and a preceding adjective, should it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "closer unit".There are no hard-and-fast rules here, so I'm not even sure what you mean by "should".

Answer (score 2):

You may find useful the common [Order of Adjectives](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adjectives-order):
[image]

We could debate about the exact order of "fresh" and "seasonal", but to save time let's assume "fresh" refers to *age* (or *quality*), and "seasonal" to *type*.  In this case, "fresh" naturally comes before "seasonal".

With two adjectives, the comma is generally optional (but helpful).  The comma separates the adjectives as distinct features, replacing the word "and":

> The service provides quick, reliable copy editing.
>
> The software delivers frequent, fast updates of market activity.

The exception is in *advertising, headlines*, or other kinds of *banners* where punctuation is kept to a minimum:

> Sale On Fresh Seasonal Produce! Today Only!

Comment: If the attributive adjectives are not interchangeable in order, is the comma acceptable? The Blue Book of Grammar and Punctuation seems to advise against it.

Comment: @Apollyon  The only time I, personally, would *not* use the comma is in a banner or headline.